# Error while trying to connect cassandra database using spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm working in a project which uses Spark streaming, Apache kafka and Cassandra. 
I use streaming-kafka integration. In kafka I have a producer which sends data using this configuration:

`props.put("metadata.broker.list", KafkaProperties.ZOOKEEPER);
props.put("bootstrap.servers", KafkaProperties.SERVER);
props.put("client.id", "DemoProducer");`

where `ZOOKEEPER = localhost:2181`, and `SERVER = localhost:9092`.

Once I send data I can receive it with spark, and I can consume it too. My spark configuration is:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("org.kakfa.spark.ConsumerData").setMaster("local[4]");
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
```

After that I am trying to store this data into cassandra database. But when I try to open session using this:

```
CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(jssc.sparkContext().getConf());
Session session = connector.openSession();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:220)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1231)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:334)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:182)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:161)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:161)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:36)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:61)
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:70)
at org.kakfa.spark.ConsumerData.main(ConsumerData.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Regarding to cassandra, I'm using default configuration:

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
- seeds: "127.0.0.1"
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
start_rpc: true
```

I can manage to connect to cassandra from the command line using cqlsh localhost, getting the following message:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042. [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.5 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4] Use HELP for help. cqlsh>
```

I used nodetool status too, which shows me this:

http://pastebin.com/ZQ5YyDyB

For running cassandra I invoke `bin/cassandra -f`

What I am trying to run is this:

```
try (Session session = connector.openSession()) {
        System.out.println("dentro del try");
        session.execute("DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS test");
        System.out.println("dentro del try - 1");
        session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1}");
        System.out.println("dentro del try - 2");
        session.execute("CREATE TABLE test.users (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
        System.out.println("dentro del try - 3");
    }
```

My pom.xml file looks like that:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have no idea why I can't connect to cassandra using spark, is it configuration bad or what i am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException:
>   unconfigured table schema_keyspaces)

That error indicates an old driver with a new Cassandra version. Looking at the POM file, we find there the spark-cassandra-connector dependency declared twice.
One uses version `1.6.0-m2`  (GOOD) and the other `1.1.0-alpha2` (old).

Remove the references to the old dependencies `1.1.0-alpha2` from your config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```